# JUnit expected tag not working as expected

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have the following test case in eclipse, using JUnit 4 which is refusing to pass. **What could be wrong?**

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testIAE() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

This exact testcase came about when trying to test my own code with the expected tag didn't work. I wanted to see if JUnit would pass the most basic test. It didn't.

I've also tested with custom exceptions as expected without luck.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This one is really weird, did some testing myself, and this code runs fine (the test is successfull)...

Comment: I added a screenshot, just to show... I'd be doubtful too.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The problem is that your `nnounceThreadTest` extends `TestCase`. Because it extends `TestCase`, the JUnit Runner is treating it as a JUnit 3.8 test, and the test is running because it starts with the word test, hiding the fact that the `@Test` annotiation is in fact not being used at all.

To fix this, remove the `extends TestCase` from the class definition.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it as advertised.

Comment: After removing the extends TestCase, I had to add the additional import to ensure I had the static assert methods.

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

Comment: Awesome job at finding the solution hidden as a hint in a screenshot

Comment: Argggghhhh, I just spent an hour and a half on this issue without finding this answer. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: The screen shot is a broken link now so we can't see what the original class looked like.  I found that if I renamed my class and my tests to no longer start with "test" that suddenly @Begin works and "expected" works too.  Thanks Yishai!

Comment: @Seansms, the original screen shot shows that the class extended TestCase. I assume that is your problem as well. Don't extend TestCase, that is the JUnit 3.8 way.

Comment: Same problem and removing "extends TestCase" fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of removing extends TestCase , you can add this to run your test case with Junit4 which supports annotation.

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)

Answer (score 3):

Just ran this in IntelliJ using JUnit 4.4:

```
   @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
   public void testExpected()
   {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
```

Passes perfectly.

Rebuild your entire project and try again.  There's something else that you're doing wrong.  JUnit 4.4 is working as advertised.