# How to dynamically add a test to test suite in JUnit 4?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I recently read ([link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extend-testcase-or-test/2635862#2635862)) about a way to statically add tests to test suite in JUnit 4? What about a dynamic way, i.e. how to add a test class if its name is known not earlier than at run-time, e.g. its name is read from XML file?

Answer (score 2):

I know how to do it. I can use JUnitExt library (http://junitext.sourceforge.net). It supports "declarative test configurations (as provided by TestNG)". See junitext.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html (How to parameterize tests using XML).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to add to an existing suite, but you can create your own suite at runtime.  The JUnitCore class lets you pass in a list of classes you want run.  These can be read in from anywhere you like including XML.