# Java JUnit test case with exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit

what's wrong with this. I have junit 4[image]

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: How do I catch the two exceptions correctly in junit, because right now they are being caught and my tests are failing.

Comment: Show us more of your test, and the stack trace of the exception. The snippet you gave doesn't even invoke the constructor. Tell us what you're trying to test.

Comment: Why did you change the question around so much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare on the `@Test` annotation that, for the test to pass, it must throw these exceptions:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testSynapseOne() {
    // test
}


@Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
public void testSynapseTwo() {
    // test
}
```

Of course, you have to be sure you're testing the right thing - currently, your tests don't make use of the constructor, which is the critical piece you want to test.

Oh - you don't want to have your tests extend `TestCase` [unless you need compatibility with JUnit3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2635946/1079354).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the annotation `@Test(expected = TheClassException.class)` to write a test which is supposed to throws the exception of class `TheClassException`