# Junit - how Java deals with class methods having Asserts

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I a quite new to Junit. I have a question on how Java runs Junit classes. I have a code like this

```
public class TestJunit1 {

        String message = "Srinivas";
        MessageUtil messageutil = new MessageUtil(message);

        @Test
        public void testPrintMessage() {
            System.out.println("Inside testPrintMessage");
            assertEquals(message, messageutil.printMessage());
        }

}

public class TestJUnit5 extends TestCase {
    protected double fValue1;
    protected double fValue2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        fValue1 = 2.0;
        fValue2 = 3.0;
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdding() {
        System.out.println("No of test cases =" + this.countTestCases());

        String name = this.getName();
        System.out.println("Test Case name is: "+name);

        this.setName("methodNewAdd");
        String newName = this.getName();
        System.out.println("New name of the test case is:"+newName);
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

public class TestSuiteDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestSuite ts = new TestSuite(TestJunit1.class, TestJunit2.class, TestJUnit5.class);
        TestResult tr = new TestResult();

        ts.run(tr);
        System.out.println("Number of test cases is:"+tr.runCount());


    }

}
```

when I run TestSuiteDemo as Java application in eclipse, it produces output from println statements from TestJUnit5 and not from TestJunit1. 
Could somebody please explain why this happens?

Regards
Srinivas

Comment: Your TestJUnit1 is not extending TestCase.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extend-testcase-or-test

Answer (score 1):

Because `TestJUnit5` extends a `TestCase` (not `TestJunit1`) so JUnit sees the test case and runs it.

From the `junit.framework.TestSuite` code, any class that *inherits* `Test` class or *extends* `TestCase` can get registered with `TestSuite` constructor.

```
private void addTestsFromTestCase(final Class<?> theClass) {
        fName = theClass.getName();
        try {
            getTestConstructor(theClass); // Avoid generating multiple error messages
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            addTest(warning("Class " + theClass.getName() + " has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()"));
            return;
        }

        if (!Modifier.isPublic(theClass.getModifiers())) {
            addTest(warning("Class " + theClass.getName() + " is not public"));
            return;
        }

        Class<?> superClass = theClass;
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (Test.class.isAssignableFrom(superClass)) {
            for (Method each : MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(superClass)) {
                addTestMethod(each, names, theClass);
            }
            superClass = superClass.getSuperclass();
        }
        if (fTests.size() == 0) {
            addTest(warning("No tests found in " + theClass.getName()));
        }
    }
```

To get `TestJunit1` to work, you will have to create an annotative `Suite`.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   TestJunit1.class,
   TestJunit2.class,
   TestJunit5.class
})

public class JunitTestSuite {  
}
```

And to run it locally:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class JunitTestSuiteRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite.class);
        for (Failure fail : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(fail.toString());
        }
        if (result.wasSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("All tests finished successfully...");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

*Source [reference](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-suite-test-example/)*.

Answer (score 0):

amoq reference to the stackoverflow post [JUnit confusion: use 'extends TestCase' or '@Test'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extend-testcase-or-test)
 is accurate. There are two main way for junit test to recognize and run your rest Junit version 3 , extend test case . Junit version 4 annotate with @Test. 
Since your test 1 has neither it is not run at all. Confirm the version of junit your eclipse is using, you could use the annotation version @Test which u might find more pleasant

Comment: You should include the reference in your answer. Comments may disappear.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers