# Nullpointer exception - JAVA Mockito

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

Probably just me being blind, but why do i get a nullpointer exception at "when(sqldummy.getAllMembers()).thenReturn(mockedMemberList);"?
Trying out Mockito for the first time, so i might have bad implementations. (I'm not quite sure).

I've been staring myself blind for a while now. System-out debugging didn't yield any real information other than it's null.

I tried moving the entire code from the @before into the actual method and it works there. But that is ugly and @Before is to handle duplicate code like this, that I would otherwise have to add to every other testmethod I create.

Please help.

```
public class TestShipHandling extends TestCase{

private static ShipHandling shipHandling;
private static SQLDUMMY sqldummy;
private static ArrayList<Member> mockedMemberList;
private static ArrayList<Ship> mockedShipList;


@Before
public void before() {
    sqldummy = mock(SQLDUMMY.class);
    mockedMemberList = new ArrayList<>();
    mockedShipList = new ArrayList<>();
    shipHandling = new ShipHandling(sqldummy);  //Instance shiphandling class with mocked SQLDUMMY

    Member m1 = new Member();
    m1.setMemberFirstName("Max");
    m1.setMemberLastName("W0w");
    m1.setMemberID("MW222");
    mockedMemberList.add(m1);

    System.out.println(mockedMemberList);
    Member m2 = new Member();
    m2.setMemberFirstName("Andrew");
    m2.setMemberLastName("Gower");
    m2.setMemberID("AG222");
    mockedMemberList.add(m2);

    Member m3 = new Member();
    m3.setMemberFirstName("Maximum");
    m3.setMemberLastName("Crispness");
    m3.setMemberID("MC999");
    mockedMemberList.add(m3);

    Ship s = new Ship();
    s.setShipName("qweqwe");
    s.setShipClass("big");
    s.setShipGunCaliber(300);
    s.setShipLength(200);
    s.setShipNGuns(30);
    mockedShipList.add(s);

}

@After
public void after() {
    System.out.println(mockedMemberList);
    mockedMemberList.clear();
    mockedShipList.clear();
}

@Test
public void testAddShipReturnsTrue() throws Exception {
    when(sqldummy.getAllMembers()).thenReturn(mockedMemberList);

    Member tempMem = sqldummy.getAllMembers().get(0);

    String shipName = "Victorium";
    String shipClass = "Battleship";
    int shipGunCaliber = 305;
    int shipLength = 320;
    int shipNGuns = 10;

    assertTrue(shipHandling.addShip(tempMem, shipName, shipClass, shipGunCaliber, shipLength, shipNGuns));
}
```

Comment: please use only information in the title

Comment: I guess `shipHandling.addShip` is accessing a method in sqldummy that returns null.

Comment: change this line Member tempMem = sqldummy.getAllMembers().get(0);
to List list = sqldummy.getAllMembers();Member tempMem = list.get(0);

Comment: Code works for me, don't see why it should do that. Are you sure that the code is the same and the exception really occours at that place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [mixing Junit3's TestCase and JUnit4's @Before and @After annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extend-testcase-or-test).

Looking to the [javadoc of TestCase](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestCase.html) you read:

> A test case defines the fixture to run multiple tests. To define a test case
>
> 1.implement a subclass of TestCase
>   2.define instance variables that store the state of the fixture
>   **3.initialize the fixture state by overriding setUp()**
>   4.clean-up after a test by overriding tearDown().

Hence to make this code work you must:

**Option 1**: Do not extend `TestCase` and import `org.junit.Assert` for the `assertTrue`.

**Option 2**: Change the name of `before()` to `setUp()`; change the name of `after()` to `tearDown()`; remove `@Test`, `@Before` and `@After` annotations.

Any option above should work, but I recommend you to use the first one (reasons on the link above).

PS: You don't need to make your fields static ;)

Comment: Ah, YES! Thank you so much! I'd never have figured that one out. NullPointers in my experience have always been a silly error like in initializing or using the wrong instance or something along those lines. Thank you good sir!