# @Test(expected = Exception.class) does not work for me, what am I missing?

Tags: java, exception, junit4, assert

I am using sts but also using mvn clean install on the command line. I created this simple to test as an example.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class QuickTest extends TestCase {

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void test() {
        throwsException();
    }

    private void throwsException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Test");
    }
}
```

My STS (Eclipse) IDE complains that the line calling the method testThrowsException(); unhandled exception type Exception.

If I try to run the test I get the same error

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type Exception
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: public void test() throws Exception { ...

Comment: this is expected behaviour. just add `throws Exception` to your test method.

Comment: Answers provided here (particularly Michael's) explains well the compilation issue. Note that extending `TestCase` is not required in JUnit 4 to declare a method as a test method. The `@Test` annotation serves this goal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extends-testcase-or-test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring `Exception` as expected in an *annotation*. This is *runtime behaviour*, as determined by JUnit. Your code *must still conform* to all of Java's normal rules at compile-time. Under Java's normal rules, when a method throws a checked exception, you must either 1) mark it as thrown in the method signature or 2) catch it and deal with it. Your code does neither. For your test, you want to do the former in order for JUnit to fail:

```
public class QuickTest extends TestCase
{
    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        throwsException();
    }
}
```

Or you can change `Exception` to `RuntimeException` in both cases so that it's an unchecked exception (i.e. not subject to the same rules).

Answer (score 4):

you need to add throws since this is a checked exception and you want the method to throw it instead of handling it ( for the test purposed)

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void test() throws Exception{
        throwsException();
    }
```