# Junit/Maven gives error No tests found when extending TestCase class

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

Part of `pom.xml` dependency is pasted below:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Pasting the contents of a TestFile that works.

Location: `~/IdeaProjects/mavenproject1/src/test/java/FirstPackage/EmployeeTest.java`

```
package FirstPackage;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EmployeeTest {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    @Test
    public void SayNothing() {
        TestCase.assertEquals("hello",e.getEmployee("hello"));
    }
}
```

**Notice how the call to assert is TestCase.assertEquals**. This works and test passes.

When I change the above code to extend `TestCase` class, I get an error that no tests are found. Why is that? (It is not a compilation error but runtime error)

Broken class

```
package FirstPackage;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EmployeeTest extends TestCase {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    @Test
    public void SayNothing() {
        assertEquals("hello",e.getEmployee("hello"));
    }
}
```

**Notice the extends TestCase and call to assertEquals without className**

Getting the below error and not sure why

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in FirstPackage.EmployeeTest

    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.fail(TestCase.java:227)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:97)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: If you called that method `testSayNothing` you might [get a different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635839/junit-confusion-use-extends-testcase-or-test) Method names start lower case anyway btw

Comment: I am on junit 4.13.2 and I have `@Test` annotation @g00se. So not sure what you mean

Comment: Remove it and see what happens when you rename it as I suggested

Comment: it worked. But why?

Comment: Read the link I posted

Comment: I had read it. But if you see my question, I had the Test annotation and hence I do not require to start test name with `test`. Isn't it? But it had not worked

Comment: This answer has a better explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151384/29470